# How to set default type of generic but allow to override it?

Tags: typescript, typescript-generics

I am creating a Table component that extracts the data from array of items. Usually, it's done using `dataKey` property. There is also `filter.key` property, which by default inherits `dataKey` value, but it can be used to override the key. I want `customLabel` function to have `value` argument which type corresponds to `Item[filter.key || dataKey]`.

Take a look on the reproduction, it contains comments and explains the problem: https://tsplay.dev/m3XLkW

There are 4 cases to cover:

1. `dataKey` exists, `filter.key` doesn't - take `dataKey` - works
2. `dataKey` exists, `filter.key` as well - take `filter.key` - doesn't work, value is union of all keys, not `Item[filter.key]`
3. `dataKey` doesn't exist, `filter.key` does - take `filter.key` - doesn't work, the same
4. both doesn't exist - results with `never`, since dev has to define one of them - works